ngx-pagination with ngx-bootstrap/pagination
In Angular, Pagination with Bootstrap
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';

The cursor is always stay in the middle when pressing Next button ?

Is this the normal angular pagination behavior ? Thanks.
The Actual Result is not same as the Expected result


Where did the expected result come from? I think the actual result is more useful for paging through lists of many pages.

The Expected Result is the behavior of ASP.NET ListView Controls. I am trying to achieve the same behavior by using Angular.
